# What happens if GTK fails to create a new object?

Tags: c, gtk

I'm using GTK for a small program and I'm wondering what happens if a widget can't be created. I haven't found any documentation regarding this.

Let's say I'm allocating a menu

```
menu = gtk_menu_new();
```

What happens if it can't be allocated? The system could not have enough memory, so I believe it can fail. How can I handle the error if it happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

perhaps:

> If any call to allocate memory fails, the application is terminated.
>   This also means that there is no need to check if the call succeeded.

from: https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Memory-Allocation.html

Comment: There is also `g_try_malloc` which returns `NULL` on failure, so you can not say for sure what happens unless you know which one is used for the widget's implementation. Also: [an up to date link to the current stable reference manual](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.38/glib-Memory-Allocation.html) instead of a 10 year old one.

Comment: I'm aware of no widget that is created using g_try_malloc. g_try_malloc is used when a huge amount of memory is requested, and you think it may fail. This not really a use case for widgets.

Answer (score -1):

```
if (menu){   //created  }
else:{}
 {
  //"cant" 
  }
```

every function will evaluate and return 1 or a object on sucess....##

if it fails to evaluate a function. then value assigned to a variable will false

Comment: and allocation is problem but there may be another problems like atribute error.